# What pipe/adapter do I need to make this sink connect to this P trap?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, interior

I'm getting ready to connect a custom vanity to a P-trap and I'm not sure what kind of pipe/connection/adapter I need.

The P-trap looks like this:

[image: p-trap]

(note that it won't be sticking out that far from the wall.  This was just a test shot for example purposes.

The sink I'm planning to use looks like this:

[image: sink top view]

Here's the bottom view of it:

[image: sink bottom view]

The sink drain hole is approximately 2 inches in diameter.

The P-trap pipe diameter is 1.5 inches in diameter.

So my question at this point is: What material/component do I need to connect these two?  Is there a "drain insert" that's made for this type of thing?  Or should I find some sort adapter/coupling to connect the stuff together?

How can I connect these two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to install a drain assembly. In a bathroom, pop-up drain assemblies are common.

[image: Pop-up drain assembly]

Here's an image of the drain assembly, with all the parts labeled.

[image: Labeled drain assembly]
<sub>(source: [naturalhandyman.com](http://www.naturalhandyman.com/iip/infplumb/i/infpop1.gif))</sub>

The tailpiece of the drain assembly, should attach to the trap assembly. If the trap is too low, an extension can be used.

When installing the drain, put a bead of plumber's putty around the drain hole of the sink. Then bed the drain flange in the plumber's putty.  From below, install the washer and nut, and thread on the tailpiece. When you tighten it down, the excess plumber's putty will squeeze out. Use you finger, or a rag to remove whatever oozes out.

Comment: To clarify: you do not connect directly to the ~2" outlet on the bottom of the sink. You would instal a drain assembly the same way as you would on a porcelain sink. The nut (part RP6140 in @Tester's image) would but-up to the underside of the ~2" sink outlet. Tightening it will compress the flange to the inside of the sink. Your p-trap is most likely 1-1/4" and a 1-1/4" drain assembly would fit though the sink's outlet.

Comment: You guys got it right... Even if the P trap was 1 1/2" the tail pipes are available for that too.

Answer (score 2):

The best advice to give you is to contact the manufacturer of this specialty sink. They may very well have had some ideas in mind when the sink design was made.

This does not appear to be a simple matter of using a standard bathroom sink drain assembly due to the way the sink overflow is designed.

The interior view also implies that a very specific sink stopper assembly is intended to be used with this sink due to the fact that the mating surface for the stopper appears to be built right into the sink. In a more standard sink design the stopper assembly and its mating part(s) are all built into the drain assembly itself.

So contact the manufacturer on this one.

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is the drain. Usually this either comes with the faucet or can be bought stand alone. But I do agree with the other answer in that it might be a part specific to this sink.